# Flutter Sign-in with Google getting warning of dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, dart, flutter

Actually I follow step from 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in#-readme-tab-

I just created project on [Firebase Console.](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/)

After creating project I added Platform iOS and Android:

**1) For iOS**

- Added bundle ID
- Download **GoogleService-Info.plist** and added to Xcode project
- Skip to install Firebase POD

**2) For Android**

- Added Package name
- Added **SHA-1**

*That's IT.*

I'm using MacOS and iOS Simulator.

When try to run app getting below warning in console.

> Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
>     CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
>     Without resolving iOS dependencies with CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS.
>     For more info, see https://flutter.io/platform-plugins
>   To install:
>     brew install cocoapods
>     pod setup

I checked **cocoapods** already installed and working well so why warning comes?

Comment: What do you get when you execute `pod --version` in a terminal?

Comment: pod --version => **1.5.3**

Comment: Looks good. Try running `pod install` in `your_project/android/`.

Comment: [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: I'd try deleting `ios/` and run `flutter create .` and then add `GoogleService-Info.plist` again (and perhaps re-apply other manual changes you may have made)

Comment: I created new project still getting same warning? Is it bug or something going wrong in my side ?

Comment: Looks like that. Haven't seen such an error before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186083/discussion-between-govaadiyo-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Do we required to install pod at iOS end ? Or flutter will manage all about it?